# Porting application from SDN 3 to SDN 4 and from Neo4j 2.3 to 3.0.1

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm faced a lot of issues while moving from SDN 3 to SDN 4 and from Neo4j 2.3 to 3.0.1. Right now I'm unable to fully port my application to new versions.

My application in not in production right now so I wanted to keep all things related to Neo4j up to date.

I'm worried about possible EOS(end of support) for  SDN 3x and Neo4j 2x so what do you think - should I make extra effort in order to move my application to a new stuff or I should keep everything as is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I was unsuccessful to port my existing application from SDN 3 to SDN 4.

In my opinion right now SDN 4 has a serious lack of a very important features like state synchronization between custom Cypher query and OGM.

Also, some of my old Cypher queries don't work on SDN 4 for a some reason with unexpected behavior.

Also, there is no paging(PageRequest) support for custom Cypher query.

I hope the future releases of SDN will change the situation.

Answer (score 1):

According to Neo4j, 2.3 may be supported for as few as 6 months longer:
http://neo4j.com/guides/upgrade/

Spring Data 3.x does not seem to be under active development, according to their changelog:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/changelog.txt
(note the last non-dependency-related changes were introduced in 3.4.0.RELEASE (2015-09-01), and even then it's not very much)

We have an application in production with both of these libraries and are discussing what to do.  It does seem like they changed quite a lot of API in SDN 4 and Neo4j 3, so it is a significant task to try to upgrade.  I can't give you a definitive answer without knowing your specifics.  But if you aren't in production yet, I would lean heavily towards dealing with the upgrade, since Neo4j 2.3 and SDN 3 do seem likely to be EOS soon.